# How can I get 2nd balance from MetaMask?

Tags: next.js, blockchain, ethereum

Please give me a solution to get 2 balance(HPB, ESR) from an account.
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a token balance, you need to know the address of the token contract, because the token balance of an address is stored on the token contract.

MetaMask only shares the saved accounts to the requesting app (and the user needs to manually confirm this action first). But it doesn't share the token addresses, that the user added to their MM UI.

So if you know the token address, you can use a simple web3 call for example:

```
const jsonAbi = {}; // JSON ABI of the token contract
const contractAddress = "0x123"; // address of the token contract
const tokenAddress = "0xfF3d"; // address of which you want to get the token balance

const token = new web3.eth.Contract(jsonAbi, contractAddress);
const balance = await token.balanceOf(tokenAddress);
```